# JMeter RestAPI - How to send json body as request along with an image(jpeg/jpg) file in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0

I am trying to send json body in JMeter (body data) for my RestAPI - PUT along with an attachment (jpeg/jpg) file. Every-time I get the response as "{"error":"Incorrect number of attachments."}".

I have the jpeg/jpg file which needs to be sent in Jmeter/bin folder.
Body Data tab in JMeter-

```
   {
     "message": {

    "attachments": [
        {
            "name": "googleImage.jpg",
            "mimeType": "image/jpg"
        }
    ],
    "messageBody": "Hello World! - Test Attachments",
    "subjectLine": "Test message - 0927T09:58",
    "messageID": "",
    "toAddress": "some reqd value"
   }
  }
```

Header has-
Content-Type- application/json
Accept- application/json, image/jpeg
Also tried with-
Accept-multipart/form-data
Accept-multipart/mixed

Comment: what version of jmeter are you using ?

Comment: I am using JMeter 4.0

Comment: try with jmeter 5.0, please show the request sent from firefox or chrome.

Comment: I am trying for RestAPI. I have the json body in "Body data" (as posted above, it's the same json body) and the attachment "googleImage.jpg" is there in jmeter/bin folder.   It's works fine when I try from SOAPUI pro, but JMeter it doesn't. Any leads for passing a json body with attachments (image) for Rest API would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

If your request works in SoapUI you should be able to convert it to JMeter at least in 2 ways:

1. Record your SoapUI test using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

   - Start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder (the easiest way is using Recording Template feature available from File -> Templates -> Recording menu)
   - Configure SoapUI to use JMeter as a proxy, it can be done in File -> Preferences -> Proxy

     [image: SoapUI Proxy For JMeter]
   - Run the request in SoapUI (if the request assumes file upload make sure to copy the file into "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
   - JMeter should capture the request under the [Recording Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)
2. It is possible to [convert SoapUI XML into Taurus YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/SoapUI/#soapui2yaml-Converting-Existing-SoapUI-Project-into-Taurus-YAML) and then generate JMX from YAML if needed.

---

It is also possible to build the request manually defining JSON and multipart payloads in the same request, however you will either need to know the request specification from your API documentation or capture the request by looking into SoapUI `Raw` tab or using an external sniffer tool like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). Check out [Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more information and example scenario implementation